# TSQL Select dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, dynamic-sql

Can anyone help me produce this output please?  I've tried writing dynamic SQL but I can't get it working.  I have an orders table and then a required columns table which contains a row per order with a comma separated list of the columns that I need to get from the orders table.

The Orders table will contain a few million rows, it doesn't have to be super fast but not take days to run.

Additional Info

The real Orders table will have 30 columns of data, not 10.

The real FullColumnList in the RequiredCols table will have 8 comma separated values or NULL in place of the column name if that order has less than 8 columns (eg 'ColName1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL')

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders(
    OrderNo INT
    ,ColName1 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName2 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName3 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName4 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName5 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName6 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName7 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName8 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName9 VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColName10 VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (OrderNo, ColName1, ColName2, ColName3, ColName4, ColName5, ColName6, ColName7, ColName8, ColName9, ColName10)
SELECT 1234, 'ColDetail1', 'ColDetail2', 'ColDetail3', 'ColDetail4', 'ColDetail5', 'ColDetail6', 'ColDetail7', 'ColDetail8', 'ColDetail9', 'ColDetail10'
UNION SELECT 2345 'ColDetail1', 'ColDetail2', 'ColDetail3', 'ColDetail4', 'ColDetail5', 'ColDetail6', 'ColDetail7', 'ColDetail8', 'ColDetail9', 'ColDetail10'
UNION SELECT 3456 'ColDetail1', 'ColDetail2', 'ColDetail3', 'ColDetail4', 'ColDetail5', 'ColDetail6', 'ColDetail7', 'ColDetail8', 'ColDetail9', 'ColDetail10'

CREATE TABLE dbo.RequiredCols (
    OrderNo INT
    ,FullColumnList VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.RequiredCols (OrderNo, FullColumnList)
SELECT 1234, 'ColName1, ColName2, ColName3'
UNION SELECT 2345, 'ColName2, ColName5, ColName6'
UNION SELECT 3456, 'ColName1, ColName3, ColName10'

CREATE TABLE dbo.FinalData (
    OrderNo INT
    ,FinalColName1 VARCHAR(20)
    ,FinalColName2 VARCHAR(20)
    ,FinalColName3 VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.FinalData (OrderNo, FinalColName1, FinalColName2, FinalColName3)
SELECT o.OrderNo, <c.FullColumnList>
FROM dbo.Orders o
JOIN dbo.RequiredCols c
    ON o.OrderNo = c.OrderNo

--REQUIRED OUTPUT
OrderNo FinalColName1   FinalColName2   FinalColName3
1234    ColDetail1      ColDetail2      ColDetail3
2345    ColDetail2      ColDetail5      ColDetail6
3456    ColDetail1      ColDetail3      ColDetail10
```

Comment: Are the columns fixed or dynamic? If fixed you could `case` each column appropriately

Comment: Will the fullColumnList always have 3 col?

Comment: You'll need to assemble the final `insert` statement in a string and then use [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to run it for each set of rows with a distinct column set. Don't forget to say "Hello!" to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261697/select-column-name-dynamically-based-on-rows-from-another-table-in-sql-server

Comment: Is your RequiredCols table schema fixed or are you in the design phase and can change?

Comment: Have you event tested the script you pasted, the data you are inserting is too large for the column definition

Comment: Column lengths amended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are better ways to do this. But this should give what you are looking for. The fullColumnList and number of columns in  finaldata should match for this to work

```
declare 
@collist varchar(max)
,@order int
,@dsql nvarchar(max)
declare @cursor cursor

truncate table FinalData

set @cursor = cursor for select FullColumnList , OrderNo from RequiredCols

open @cursor 

fetch next from @cursor into @collist, @order

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @dsql = N'insert into FinalData select OrderNo, '+ @collist +'
        from Orders
        where  OrderNo = @orderp'

        exec sp_executesql @dsql, N'@orderp int',@orderp = @order

        fetch next from @cursor into @collist, @order
    end

select * from FinalData
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go now

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you go, it's not pretty but it's fully set based and no d-sql required.

```
with c as (
    select c.OrderNo, x.col , Row_Number() over (partition by orderno order by (select 1)) seq
    from requiredcols c
    cross apply (
        select LTrim(value) col from String_Split(c.FullColumnList,',') 
    )x
),cols as (
select orderno, Max(col1) col1, Max(col2) col2, Max(col3) col3 from (
    select orderno, case when seq=1 then col end col1, case when seq=2 then col end col2, case when seq=3 then col end col3
    from c
)x group by orderno
)
select o.orderno,
    case col1
        when 'colname1' then o.colname1
        when 'colname2' then o.colname2
        when 'colname3' then o.colname3
        when 'colname4' then o.colname4
        when 'colname5' then o.colname5
        when 'colname6' then o.colname6
        when 'colname7' then o.colname7
        when 'colname8' then o.colname8
        when 'colname9' then o.colname9
        when 'colname10' then o.colname10
    end FinalColName1,
    case col2
        when 'colname1' then o.colname1
        when 'colname2' then o.colname2
        when 'colname3' then o.colname3
        when 'colname4' then o.colname4
        when 'colname5' then o.colname5
        when 'colname6' then o.colname6
        when 'colname7' then o.colname7
        when 'colname8' then o.colname8
        when 'colname9' then o.colname9
        when 'colname10' then o.colname10
    end FinalColName1,
    case col3
        when 'colname1' then o.colname1
        when 'colname2' then o.colname2
        when 'colname3' then o.colname3
        when 'colname4' then o.colname4
        when 'colname5' then o.colname5
        when 'colname6' then o.colname6
        when 'colname7' then o.colname7
        when 'colname8' then o.colname8
        when 'colname9' then o.colname9
        when 'colname10' then o.colname10
    end FinalColName1
from cols c join orders o on o.orderno=c.orderno
```

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Comment: This is true, although in my experience at least, it has always been the case, at least with small data sets. This is also why I asked if the design could be changed as ideally to accomplish this you would want to already have the RequiredCols properly normalised with 1 row per column instead of multiple values per column, where you can then then specify the column ordinal position as a row number, eliminating the need to parse or split the string.

Comment: Well, I suppose as long as it's _documented_ as undependable, you might as well put it into production knowing that you can fix it later. You could use something like [Jeff Moden's string splitter](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function) that provides an `ItemNumber` for each `Item` split from the string. Otherwise it's much like finding that a query "always" returns the rows in the order you want without an `order by` clause. What are the chances that an update to the query optimizer might change the order of the results?

Comment: Yes I agree - using the built-in function is quick and easy espeicially for a demo, however the OP is now aware of any caveats and it would be no problem to substute an alternative function - and JM is very dependable!

Answer (score 0):

you can select the column names into a table using the schema system table then create a concatenated variable with the column names and insert the column names into a dynamic nvarchar sql